# how to get JDK 7 for Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, java

In order to run some tools for a project I'm working on, I need to install specifically JDK 7. I already have JDK 8 up and running.

I searched in Oracle and open-jdk web sites but seems to be deprecated, does anybody know where can I get it?

Thanks in advance for your answers/comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Umm...

[Java SE 7 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html)

[JDK 7 Installation for Mac OS X](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html)

Comment: Well, I had tried that in a previous opportunity as I said, but now I'm being able to download it. I'll accept your answer when I got it installed. Thanks